# How to deploy web application to Tomcat in Eclipse when placeholders need to be replaced with a value?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, ant

It is a maven project in Eclipse. We use ant clean package (ant call maven target) to build the war. During the build, ant use ExpandProperties to replace the placeholders in properties files.

For example, one placeholder in properties file like:

```
stub=${stubvalue}
```

During build, ant will replace the placeholder `${stubvalue}` with a value from ant properties. So, finally all the placeholders will become actual value in the war file. Then the war file can be deploy and run successfully in tomcat.

Now in Eclipse, we create a tomcat server. Add and publish the web app to Tomcat server. However, obviously all the placeholders won't be replaced and deploy is failed when try start the tomcat in eclipse.

In this situation, what should be the proper solution?

Comment: Is your build Maven based or Ant based?

Comment: it is maven project and has pom.xml. but we have build.xml and use ant to do some tasks for example use ant expandproperties to replace the placeholders in properties files. 
so to build the war, call 'ant clean package'. ant actually call maven target to build the war.

Comment: Why not using those Ant scripts from inside maven ?

Comment: You should make a clear decision either use ant or Maven but not both. Building a WAR with Maven is usually just defining packaging type war and that's it...Why are you using Ant to create War does not make sense..Replacing properties can be done [in maven using via filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Comment: thank you all for the comments. I use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load the properties since it's a spring application. it works. But still have one problem about the log4j. currently there is log4j.xml in the war. and log level is a token which is replaced by build script. for example dev server will use level DEBUG, and production server use level INFO. and the level can be configured in external properties file. now I want the token value in log4j.xml can be identified by application itself. what's the best practice for this or idea?

Comment: I want token still in log4j.xml ,but can be identified by application itself based on the properties. means don't want the token interpolate during the build.